# Google App Engine: portable SDK or way of uploading?

Tags: google-app-engine

I've used Google App Engine, and as far as I know the only way to update my application files on Google's servers is to use the App Engine SDK.  And as far as I know the App Engine SDK is a Mac or Windows package, which is not portable (requires installation on the local machine).

I need a portable version, or another way to update my application files on Google's servers using a Mac.  I found this https://code.google.com/p/appengine-portable/ which purports to offer portable versions for Windows, but not Mac.

1. Is there a way for me to use the App Engine SDK on Mac without installing?
2. Is there any alternative way for me to update my application files on Google's servers?

Answer (score 1):

This is not where you looking for, but have a look at this post: http://googleappengine.blogspot.nl/2012/07/develop-in-cloud-with-exos-cloud-ide.html

Answer (score 0):

I am only talking about the Python SDK here. You haven't said which .

Just use the linux SDK, and run that on Mac or Windows.  I haven't used mac. But I do appengine development on Windows and Linux and have never used the Launcher.  Just follow the directions for unix on windows.  (Well change your file paths and slashes ;-)

The python SDK and dev server is all pure python.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows and OS X packages are just the the SDK and the GUI launcher. As far as I know the SDK is pure Python and portable. Either use the SDK that comes with installer or download the SDK alone.

The linux version on the documentation download page contains only the SDK, or get it on the Google App Engine googlecode project (it will be called google_appengine_x.x.x.zip):

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/downloads/list

Simply download the SKD, extract it somewhere (on my Mac, I link it to `/usr/local/google_appengine` because some script like `nosegae` expects it there, but it's not necessary). The SDK doesn't need to be installed, doesn't need to be in path. You can run appcfg.py from the SDK directory or using the absolute path.

Below is the Makefile I am using to run and upload an app (with `make serve` and `make upload`):

```
PYTHON=$(shell pwd)/venv/bin/python
GAE=/usr/local/google_appengine
APPSERVER=${GAE}/dev_appserver.py
APPCFG=${GAE}/appcfg.py
PORT=8080
SRC=./src

.PHONY: serve upload test

serve:
    open "http://localhost:${PORT}"
    ${PYTHON} ${APPSERVER} --port=${PORT} ${SRC}

upload:
    ${PYTHON} ${APPCFG} --oauth2 update ${BUILD}

test:
    cd  ${SRC}; ${PYTHON} runtest.py
```